# Compiling SWF runtime from adobeAir application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have problem in creating swf file runtime from an adobe air application. For example I create animation using https://github.com/jamesflorentino/Flip-Planes-AS3, I have converted the Sprite extension to MovieClip, the animation runs very good. Now I would like to make the animation could be save as swf file by user.

I have tried as3swf with script like this:

```
private function createSwf():void{
    //let make example the Main class is taken from github above
    var _main:Main = new Main();
    // in this case i use AS3SWF plugin
    var _swf:SWF = new SWF(_main.loaderInfo.bytes);
    // this is for copy byteArray from the _swf convertor
    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    _swf.publish(buffer);        
    saveToDesktop(buffer);
}

private function saveToDesktop(_ba:ByteArray):void{
  // create the file on the desktop
  var myFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("demo.swf");
  // create a FileStream to write the file
  var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
  // add a listener so you know when its finished saving
  fs.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileWritten);
  // open the file
  fs.openAsync(myFile, FileMode.WRITE);   
  // write the bytearray to it
  fs.writeBytes(_ba);
  // close the file
  fs.close();
}

private function fileWritten(e:Event):void{
  trace("new swf file is created");
}
```

After all those process i got generated swf in my desktop folder with name demo.swf but when i open the file, it is only a white background with error message:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.events::NativeWindowBoundsEvent could not be found.
at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:278]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2627]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

please help me what is the best way to create swf file runtime, both from script side or command line side as long as not server side because it is desktop application.

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create a SWF file at runtime?  Meaning your AIR Application will take some input and generate a SWF File?  Or are you asking about something else?  If you want to build a SWF from AIR; you may consider bundling the Flex Framework with your application and use a NativeProcess to trigger it.  Or you may want to review this: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf which should include information on the SWF File format, so you can build it "Bit by bit".

Comment: Yes I mean that my air application will take some inputs from user like text or image and there's like button "Save as SWF", then the air application will convert user's work to swf file and save it to desktop folder.

Comment: In that case; I think I gave you two proper suggestions for creating a SWF at runtime.  I'll turn it into a formal answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a SWF at runtime is not going to be the same as taking an in memory byte array representation of an animation and saving it with a SWF extension.

If you want to build a SWF from AIR; you may consider bundling the Flex Framework with your application and use a [NativeProcess](http://www.seriousmagic.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html) to trigger mxmlc to generate a SWF.  You'll need source code [or SWCs] to do this, though, it won't work with already compiled assets/classes from your running application.

Or you may want to review [the file format for a SWF](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) and go about creating it manually from your AIR application.  I have no doubt this is possible, but I do not expect it to be trivial.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, but sorry, it's hard for me to understand the pdf, specially if i have tween animation, it would be hard for bit allocation. I am interested with nativeprocess but need to find more information about it's dependency plugin of mxmlc if it runs on any OS, and how to include the embedded content or assets. is mxmlc stand alone application? i mean to run it, doesnt need to install anything or include any library in air app, if my user has not experience or installed flash builder in their OS. sorry if my statement hard to understood by you

Comment: mxmlc is just the name of the compiler included as part of the Flex FRamework.  If you build your application through Flash Builder; then you are using MXMLC.  There should be a plethora of information about compiling apps w/ MXMLC; just search for information on Flex Compiler Arguments.  The problems you may run into with that approach is the size of the Flex SDK "Ballooning" your application and getting permission to distribute the non-open-source pieces of the Flex SDK (Such as AIR SDK and the FlashGlobals )